# Reduce log level in Sonar 2.1.x

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube

I have a Maven 3.x build that uses Sonar 2.1.x for quality control. The maven-sonar plugin is used from inside Jenkins to run the Sonar checks.
During the Jenkins build, when Sonar kicks in, it logs A LOT of not so useful information at INFO level:

```
[INFO] [15:29:14.195] Java version: 1.6
[INFO] [15:29:20.853] Execute PMD 4.3 done: 6658 ms
[INFO] [15:29:20.853] Sensor PmdSensor done: 6658 ms
[INFO] [15:29:20.854] Sensor ProfileSensor...
[INFO] [15:29:21.186] Sensor ProfileSensor done: 332 ms
[INFO] [15:29:21.187] Sensor ProfileEventsSensor...
[INFO] [15:29:21.190] Sensor ProfileEventsSensor done: 3 ms
[INFO] [15:29:21.190] Sensor ProjectLinksSensor...
[INFO] [15:29:21.192] Sensor ProjectLinksSensor done: 2 ms
[INFO] [15:29:21.192] Sensor VersionEventsSensor...
[INFO] [15:29:21.198] Sensor VersionEventsSensor done: 6 ms
[INFO] [15:29:21.198] Sensor Maven dependencies...
[INFO] [15:29:21.261] Sensor Maven dependencies done: 63 ms
...
```

The log is quite big. I have been trying to find a way to set the log level to WARN with no luck. Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no way to mute this INFO-level log.

Comment: No, it's coming from a SonarQube component (more exactly the sonar-core-plugin).

Answer (score 0):

As discussed [here](https://lists.apache.org/thread/kc7f76qg4domn8t8p54svt021ks004dn) log level can be changed at the maven plugin level.

Run `mvn` with `-Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.showLogName=true` it will show the logger name with log like below

```
2022-11-09T05:47:18.8604059Z [INFO] org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.SonarQubeMojo - SCM writing changed lines (done) | time=83ms
2022-11-09T05:47:18.8604819Z [INFO] org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.SonarQubeMojo - Analysis report generated in 287ms, dir size=5.2 MB
2022-11-09T05:47:18.8605606Z [INFO] org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.SonarQubeMojo - Analysis report compressed in 1993ms, zip size=4.1 MB
2022-11-09T05:47:18.8606333Z [INFO] org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.SonarQubeMojo - Analysis report uploaded in 282ms
```

then on executing `mvn` with `-Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.SonarQubeMojo=error` it will change the log level.