# Sonar Runner default logging level

Tags: sonarqube

Is it possible to change the default logging level of a sonar runner from INFO to WARN or similar? Our nightly SonarQube analysis is blowing the Team City logs out with huge amounts of entries. According to the source, the logging is standard slf4j but when i've tried to reconfigure it, it doesn't work.

According to the docs, least verbose level supported is info; can this be overridden?

http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Server+Log+Management

Thanks
M

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer is NO

Refer: [Reduce log level in Sonar 2.1.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21000116/reduce-log-level-in-sonar-2-1-x)

But other than this if you see logging of other sonar plugins you might, may have log level set to WARN.